# How to auto-update data on the page, Angular 7 and Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring, websocket

I am trying to implement the page, where data updates in real time. I was trying to implement some web socket for this matter, but basically all examples and tutorials stands, that there is need for message being sent (idea in my project is, that data will be loaded from different source, therefore I dont have any post functions, only get). Situation is getting more complex, because this is basically details page, which loads results by specific id.

Therefore my question is - how can I implement update in real time?

This is from Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("data/{data_id}")
public Optional<Data> findByData_id(@PathVariable("data_id") Long data_id){
Optional<Data> data = dataRepository.findById(data_id);
return data;
}
```

from data.service.ts

```
getDataById(data_id: number): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<Data[]>('http://localhost:8080/data/' + data_id)
}
```

from data.details.component.ts

```
const tracker_id = +this.route.snapshot.params["data_id"];
this.data_table.getDataById[data_id]
.subscribe(data_table=> {
this.data_table.data_table = data_table as Data[];
this.data_table_var = this.data_table.data_table;
```

Comment: Please show how you are using `getDataById()` in your component

Comment: @dileepkumarjami edited with getting data in component

Answer (score 0):

If you want update data real time, you need use web socket.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
    }
}
```

This is good reference
https://medium.com/oril/spring-boot-websockets-angular-5-f2f4b1c14cee

Comment: I was trying to implement by this guid, but didnt quite get, how to apply it to my model.